# Interpolate data with multiple columns

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am new to Python. I am trying to interpolate data values from a data set that looks like:
a = [45.0,0.0017317314,-0.00274,...]
[45.07,0.00173326,-0.002278,...]
.
.
.

I want to find the values of the data from the second to the last column at certain values of the data in the first column.

I have tried the following code:

```
interp_data = np.interp(45.01,a[:,0],a[:,1])
```

as an initial try to find the value of one data point for one column. However, it returns the error 'object too deep for desired array'

However, the following works in the shell

```
>>> xp = [45.0, 45.074969417037, 45.224757625296, 45.523726383073]

>>> fp = [1.73145123922036E-002, 1.73326024230735E-002, 1.73689532454203E-002, 1.74423417607930E-002]

>>> import numpy

>>> numpy.interp(45.1, xp, fp)

0.017338676881704793
```

Also, I would like to do this for multiple values as:

```
for i in range(len(a)):

 for j in range(a.shape[1]):
   interp_data = np.interp(values,a[:,j],a[:,j])
```

where values is an array of the data points at which I want to interpolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is probably caused by a being a different shape than you expect. I get:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((10,2))
>>> print np.interp(0,a[:,0],a[:,1])
0.0

>>> a = np.zeros((10,2,3))   #note incorrect shape
>>> print np.interp(0,a[:,0],a[:,1])
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Once you get the shape of a sorted out you can just do

```
points = #the 1D array of data points you want to interpolate to
interp_data = np.interp(points,a[:,0],a[:,1])
```

Note also that np.interp will give you linear interpolation only. For more complicated interpolants you need to use scipy.interpolate (which is fantastic!). I'm a big fan of UnivariateSpline.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is the shape as my array a looks like:                                [[ 0.01731451]
 [ 0.0173326 ]
 [ 0.01736895]]
rather than                                                                                      [0.01731454, 0.0173326, ...] I think I need to unpack the elements from the array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to acces a list in an incorrect way. Lists are accessed with a[1][:] (e.g.). With this you will get all the values of the second element of the list.
As an example, you can do this:

```
xp = [0,1,2,3,4]
fp = [[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7,8]]
np.interp(1.5,xp,fp[0])
3.5
np.interp(1.5,xp,fp[1])
4.5
np.interp(1.5,xp,fp[2])
5.5
```

So if you want to have all your Y data in a list, you just need to access the first element of the list and you access to the data contained in the first list element, something like if you access the first row of an array you get all the data contained on all the columns, the difference is that you don't need to specify the (1,:) only [1] for the "second row" of the handler.